# Replace a string to a value in dict using Python

Tags: python, dictionary, string-matching

Suppose I have a list of dictionary

```
    [{'TELEPHONE': '111', 'STATUS': 'BUSY'}, {'TELEPHONE': '122', 'STATUS': 'BUSY'}, 
    {'TELEPHONE': '133', 'STATUS': 'FREE'}]
```

and I have a sentence "PHONE is STATUS". I want to replace the keyword from the sentence to the values in the dictionary. So the output should be

111 is BUSY
122 is BUSY
133 is FREE

Since STATUS matches the key in the dictionary, so I can use re to replace it,

```
    pattern = re.compile(r'\b(' + '|'.join(val.keys()) + r')\b')
    result = pattern.sub(lambda x: val[x.group()], text)
```

but the pattern PHONE is different to the key TELEPHONE in the dictionary, is there a similar way to do such replacement? I don't want to change the keys in the dictionary. Can I do something like "if I meet "PHONE", then I retrieve using the key "TELEPHONE" in the dict?"

Comment: You could just change TELEPHONE to PHONE in the dictionary, then use your new dictionary with PHONE and STATUS.

Comment: I don't understand where the string "PHONE is STATUS" comes into play. Your output could be generated from the list of dictionaries alone. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Assuming your list of dictionaries is called `dicts`, you can try the following: `sentence = "TELEPHONE is STATUS"; " ".join(" ".join(d.get(y) if y in d else y for y in sentence.split()) for d in dicts)`.

Comment: Sorry for the unclear. The problem is that there are many different patterns. One could be "PHONE is STATUS", or it may be "the status of PHONE is STATUS". I have to follow the pattern and do the replacement one by one.

Comment: `" ".join(" ".join(d.get(y) if y in d else y for y in sentence.replace('PHONE', 'TELEPHONE').split()) for d in dicts)` replaces `PHONE` with `TELEPHONE` and does what my previous comment intends to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
import re
sentence = "PHONE is STATUS"
keys = re.findall('[A-Z]+', sentence)
s = [{'TELEPHONE': '111', 'STATUS': 'BUSY'}, {'TELEPHONE': '122', 'STATUS': 'BUSY'}, {'TELEPHONE': '133', 'STATUS': 'FREE'}]
final_data = ' '.join([' is '.join([[b for a, b in i.items() if a.endswith(keys[0])][0], i[keys[-1]]]) for i in s])
```

Output:

```
'111 is BUSY 122 is BUSY 133 is FREE'
```

Comment: Thanks. This one looks like matching the substring of the key? Is there any other way that matches "COST" to "PRICE", instead of "PHONE" to "TELEPHONE"?

Comment: @WillN.Walker I believe that that additional match that you just posted is out of scope with the problem. Please post the input and dictionary you have to correlate with "COST" and "PRICE"

Comment: For example, the dict could be [{'ITEM': 'APPLE', 'PRICE': '100'}, {'ITEM': 'BANANA', 'PRICE': '50'}], and the pattern is "The cost of ITEM is COST". And the result should be "The cost of APPLE is 100", "The cost of BANANA is 50". I wanted to do the look up in dict using PRICE for the word COST.

Comment: @WillN.Walker that is more of a Natural Language Processing problem. You would have to declare a dictionary with a key of "PRICE" and have a list of correlating values such as "COST", or "VALUE", or "MONEY".

Answer (score 1):

I would create a fallback key dictionary, so if PHONE isn't found, it looks for a corresponding key in the dict that we cannot change, using chained `get` calls with default values. I'd apply that on each word & rebuild the sentence

```
dl = [{'TELEPHONE': '111', 'STATUS': 'BUSY'}, {'TELEPHONE': '122', 'STATUS': 'BUSY'},
    {'TELEPHONE': '133', 'STATUS': 'FREE'}]

# synonyms dict, you can add as many as you want
mk = {"PHONE" : "TELEPHONE", "STATE" : "STATUS"}


for d in dl:
    print(" ".join(d.get(w,d.get(mk.get(w),w)) for w in "PHONE is STATUS".split()))
```

result:

```
111 is BUSY
122 is BUSY
133 is FREE
```

the advantage of this method is that there's no linear lookup. The problem is that both `get` are performed, which can be solved with a `or` short circuit:

```
print(" ".join(d.get(w) or d.get(mk.get(w),w) for w in "PHONE is STATUS".split()))
```

now if `w` is in `d`, it doesn't evaluate the second part of the expression.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
l = [{'TELEPHONE': '111', 'STATUS': 'BUSY'}, {'TELEPHONE': '122', 'STATUS': 'BUSY'}, {'TELEPHONE': '133', 'STATUS': 'FREE'}]
print("".join(["{} is {}".format(
    i['TELEPHONE'], i['status']) for i in l]))
```

Comment: it says "invalid syntax", when i try in IDLE ( Python 3.6.3 Shell )

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell what you're trying to accomplish but I think you have a phone list and are getting log messages to update their status. Try this:

```
import re

status_update = '111 is BUSY'
status_re = re.compile('(\d+) is ([A-Z]+)')

phone, new_status = status_re.match(status_update).groups()
found = False
for val in phone_list:
    if phone == val['TELEPHONE']:
        val['STATUS'] = new_status
        found = True
if not Found:
    print('phone not found')
else:
    print('phone status updated')
```